# Angular 6 multiple apps in one project - how to redirect to the sub app

Tags: angular

I am creating Angular 6 project where I will have multiple apps. For example I have `'ApplicaitonOne'` and `'ApplicationTwo'` in my project. I have default app at the parent level. I want to load `'ApplicationOne'` when I hit the `localhost:4200`. Right now when I hit the localhost it goes to default application which is at the parent level.

I want to know what is the best approach to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

use `ng serve ApplicationOne` to start your sub application.

if you want to serve multiple projects at the same time, please add the `--port` parameter to use different port.

Comment: is it possible to have default route defined where I can lazy load the application which I want as a default loaded app?